# Ckeditor allowedContent not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor with certain set of user defined toolbars in it.Now if I use this code in config.js,

```
config.allowedContent = 'img[!src,alt,width,height]{float}';
```

the ckeditor shows only the toolbars for the above tags. Other tools are ignored or removed. I do not want inline style in images. What else can I use to remove inline styling in images without using `replace()` function in ckeditor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add all the content you can allow to the rules. That way you have complete control over the source and it's easier than you would think.

Currently it's not possible to disallow specific content - but follow closely this trac issue: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10276 - it is about creating exactly this; a disallowed content rule.